# C Linked List - pointer to incomplete class is not allowed

Tags: c++, linked-list, char, visual-studio-2015, stack

I am trying to implement a stack which holds a linked list of char types. When I try to return the value found in the top node, it gives me the error above.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "header4AB.h"

typedef struct {
    struct node_t * top;
    int max_size;
    int used_size;
} Stack;

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
}node_t;


Stack * stack(int max_size) {
    Stack * S = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    S->top = NULL;
    S->max_size = max_size;
    S->used_size = 0;
    return S;
}

bool push(Stack * S, char p) {
    if (S->used_size != S->max_size) {
            node_t * temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            temp->val = p;
            temp->next = S->top;
            S->top = temp;
            S->used_size++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool pop(Stack * S) {
    node_t * temp;
    if (S->top == NULL)
        return false;
    temp = S->top;
    S->top = temp->next;
    free(temp);

    return true;
}

char top(Stack * S) {
    if (S->top != NULL) {
        return S->top->val; //error here
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to the concept of a Linked List in a fixed size stack, and I have not tested my code yet so I do not know if it works or not. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must define `node_t` before `Stack`, and use either `struct node` or `node_t` not `struct node_t`.

Comment: Is this really what your compiler says? There are no classes in C.

Comment: @n.m. I guess the real error is: _error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type_

Comment: @n.m I quoted the error from the compiler (Visual Studio Enterprise 2015)...however LPs answer solved it.

Comment: You may want to enable and read [compiler warnings](http://ideone.com/iSySds).

Comment: If you get such a message, this is not C, but C++. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struct must be like

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
}node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t * top;
    int max_size;
    int used_size;
} Stack;
```

Or

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};

typedef struct {
    struct node * top;
    int max_size;
    int used_size;
}Stack;

Stack * stack(int max_size) {
    Stack * S = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    S->top = NULL;
    S->max_size = max_size;
    S->used_size = 0;
    return S;
}

bool push(Stack * S, char p) {
    if (S->used_size != S->max_size) {
            struct node * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->val = p;
            temp->next = S->top;
            S->top = temp;
            S->used_size++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool pop(Stack * S) {
    struct node * temp;
    if (S->top == NULL)
        return false;
    temp = S->top;
    S->top = temp->next;
    free(temp);

    return true;
}

char top(Stack * S) {
    if (S->top != NULL) {
        return S->top->val; //error here
    }
}
```

Comment: that was it! I do not quite understand why it wasn't given me an error in the line `struct node_t top`...makes it much harder to spot

Comment: Error is triggered first time you are dereferencing that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    struct node_t * top;   //Here you are using node_t type. To use this you must define this before. This causes you error.
    int max_size;
    int used_size;
} Stack;
```

To solve:

Declare `node_t` before you use it in `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `struct node_t` defined in your code. Use either `struct node` or `node_t`, or change all occurrences of `node_t` to `node`.

In language-legalese, typedef names and struct tags live in different namespaces. `X` and `struct X` are unrelated (unless the program happens to `typedef struct X X`).